# Unresolved reference to dgemm when using OpenBLAS

Tags: fortran, gfortran, mingw-w64, msys2, openblas

I have been trying for some time to compile and link the OpenBLAS lib to multiply to matrices together using dgemm.  I finally was able to compile the OpenBLAS after installing MSYS2 and the mingw64 packages from MSYS2 using pacman.  My intention is to use the OpenBLAS as a static lib.  So I wrote a simple fortran code to multiply the matrices together using dgemm.  Here is the fortran code:

```
program gcc_fun

 implicit none
            
! Variables
 real*8 x(2,2),y(2,2),z(2,2)

 x(1,1) = 3.d0
 x(2,1) = 2.d0
 x(1,2) = 1.d0
 x(2,2) = 4.d0
 y(1,1) = .5d0
 y(2,1) = 1.d0
 y(1,2) = 2.d0
 y(2,2) = .75d0
 
    call dgemm( 'n', 'n', 2, 2, 2, 1,x,2,y, 2, 1, z, 1)

! Body of gcc_fun
print *, 'Z = ', z

end program gcc_fun
```

Here is my makefile to try and link:

```
CCC      = gcc   -g -Iincludem -Iincludev   -c   -O0
WARN     = -Wall
CCCX     = x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  -m64 -s -Iincludem -Iincludev   -c   -O2 -DNDEBUG
fort     = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -s -Iincludem -Iincludev -fno-underscoring -c   -O2 -DNDEBUG
#fort     = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -s -Iincludem -Iincludev -c   -O2 -DNDEBUG

OBJECTS = \
     obj/gcc_fun.o 



          
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Make the Guidance Object Library (GNC_Lib.a) and the Executable (guideUnitTest)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


gcc_fun.exe:  $(OBJECTS)
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -o gcc_fun.exe   -L./ -lopenblas_haswell-r0.3.10  $(OBJECTS) 

#------------------------------------------
#                object file targets 
#------------------------------------------

    
obj/gcc_fun.o: \
gcc_fun.f90
    $(fort) $(WARN) -o $@ gcc_fun.f90
```

I run the make file with `make -f makefile_name` and get unresolved reference to dgemm. I have tried it with and without the no-underscoring option to no avail. Here is the actual error:

```
$ make -f Makefile_gcc_fun.mak
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -s -Iincludem -Iincludev -fno-underscoring -c   -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -o obj/gcc_fun.o gcc_fun.f90
f951.exe: Warning: Nonexistent include directory 'includem' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
f951.exe: Warning: Nonexistent include directory 'includev' [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
gcc_fun.f90:27:2:

   27 |   x(2,1) = 2.d0
      |  1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
gcc_fun.f90:28:2:

   28 |   x(1,2) = 1.d0
      |  1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
gcc_fun.f90:29:2:

   29 |   x(2,2) = 4.d0
      |  1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
gcc_fun.f90:31:2:

   31 |   y(2,1) = 1.d0
      |  1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
gcc_fun.f90:32:2:

   32 |   y(1,2) = 2.d0
      |  1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
gcc_fun.f90:33:2:

   33 |   y(2,2) = .75d0
      |  1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1) [-Wtabs]
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran -o gcc_fun.exe   -L./ -lopenblas_haswell-r0.3.10  obj/gcc_fun.o
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj/gcc_fun.o:gcc_fun.f90:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `dgemm'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile_gcc_fun.mak:19: gcc_fun.exe] Error 1
```

When I inspect the OpenBLAS library with nm I get this:

```
$ nm -g libopenblas_haswell-r0.3.10.a | grep dgemm
dgemm.obj:
0000000000000000 T dgemm_
```

So it looks like dgemm is an external object and I should be able to call it.  I am sure I am missing something easy so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subroutine is just `dgemm`, not `dgemm_`. You just call it

```
call dgemm()
```

The symbol name you see using `nm` can differ depending on your toolchain (compiler, operating system,...). It matters if you do interoperability of different programming languages. However, if you stay within Fortran, you do not need to worry without it.

---

Important:

The static library being linked should be placed *after* the file that uses the library in the linking command. Only then the  dependecies can be resolved. If this is the actual issue, we will have some duplicates to link to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried it with just `call dgemm` and the error changes to `undefined reference to dgemm`

Comment: @DavidAlldredge But why do you use `-fno-underscoring`? Or is it acually used or isn't? What is the purpose of your `fort` in the Makefile? Is it used at all?

Comment: This simple examples stems from my actual application that is a mix fortran, c, c++ code. There I need fortran to not append the "_". So the no-underscoring option. In this simple example, I was just trying to get this to work before moving on the to larger, more complicated, application. Since this is the first time I have tried to link the OpenBLAS , I am not sure that I compiled it correctly using mingw_w64 cross compilers. If this simple example should work as shown, then I guess there is something in how I compiled OpenBLAS?

Comment: I just saw your amended comment. I define `fort` and then use it to compile the .f90 file that is shown at the top of this page.

Comment: @DavidAlldredge But there is no `--fno-underscoring` in the compiler output you show. I do not see how `fort` is used at all. Please post a complete output including all compiling steps. Make a `make clean` before that (or just delete all .o files).

Comment: I updated the main post to show the results of the clean compile. I only showed the one with the `no-underscoring` but get the same error without with the exception of the unresolved reference changed from `dgemm` to `dgemm_`

Comment: Your command line does not contain the library.  You need to tell gfortran where to find the library and the library's name.  Perhaps, -L{path_to_library} -lopenblas

Comment: @evets There is some `   -L./ -lopenblas_haswell-r0.3.10 ` used, but it is placed too soon in the command, it should be placed *after* the .o file name.

Comment: @Vladimir, yes, I realized that about 10 seconds after posting.  With static libraries and object files order matters.

Comment: Ha! I knew it was a stupid mistake on my part.  So it now compiles but the exec fails because it is looking for `libgfortran-5.dll` The application I will ultimately build will need to run on any Windows machine and may not have fortran (again why I want to statically link the OpenBLAS) Can this new error be fixed with `-static` or linking `'lgfortran` or something else? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: So I tried -static and at least for the simple example it worked. Thanks for all the comments!!!!!!